# SSRS 2014 Report Viewer not showing Export to Excel, Word buttons

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2014

We've a fresh installation of SQL Server Standard 2014 edition with Reporting Services - Native on Windows 2019 Standard Edition. Our .Net MVC application is only showing PDF when Export dropdown button clicked. All software are x64.
What could've gone wrong? We've the similar setup on Windows 10 PC & all expected export formats are available when the export button is clicked.

Comment: We did a fresh installation after a whole system format & got the export features back. Don't know what went wrong in the first instance. How to close this thread as answered?

Comment: You'll need to answer your own question.

Answer (score 1):

We did a fresh installation after a whole system format & got the export features back. Closing this thread as answered.